# How to change JAXB Marshaller line separator

Tags: java, xml

I Want To Separate xml line when Generate The XML

My Code :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(student, new File(fileName));    
    marshaller.marshal(student, System.out);
```

MyOutPut:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HNkk.png)

Expected OutPut:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqd0p.png)

I Got Some Info About This Problem:----

> It is worthwhile checking the different kind of line ends. When I
>   first programmed, I was using a Teletype. I had to push the CR =
>   Campbell Ritchie key at the end of every line. Then I had to push the
>   LF = line-feed = \n key to move the paper up. Older Macs used \r as a
>   line-end sequence. DOS and Windows® still use CR-LF (\r\n) at the end
>   of a line. Unix-like systems always use LF alone (\n) .That means, if
>   you are working on a Linux system, there will be no \r characters in a
>   normal text file. You are going to have to do something to allow for
>   that difference if you transfer the file to a Windows® system which
>   uses \r\n. but i am currently Generate XMl on Windows System but still
>   its consider Unix and Produce (\n) end of the line.. please any one
>   help me about this problem ...

---

Comment: Please add the outputs as text.

Comment: i was compare my xml file this time its show problem, thats why when i am going to copy output this time not showing actually problem , so thats why , i am attaching the image